# Pidgin getting "Connection Refused" whenever I connect to IRC server

Tags: windows-7, pidgin, irc

On my win 7 x64 machine using pidgin 2.6.3 I cannot connect to any IRC server.  I have tried most of the North American servers, as well as my workplace's internal server with no luck.  I have tried from work as well as from home but different networks have no effect.  I keep getting Unable to Connect: Connection refused.

It work fine 3 weeks ago on this very machine running Win 7 x64.  But then I re-imaged, and did not backup my .purple folder.  Which I had used for the past 2 years and originally created on a vista install.

I can connect using this install of Pigin to yahoo and msn with no problems.  Just not to irc.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's caused by your firewall?

---

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, run `telnet` from there, and enter:

```
open chat.freenode.net 6667
```

If it greets you with something like this...

```
NOTICE AUTH :*** Looking up your hostname...
NOTICE AUTH :*** Checking ident
```

...then either your firewall is blocking `pidgin.exe`, or your configuration is incorrect somehow.

---

If Windows 7 doesn't have `telnet` anymore (which I heard but cannot confirm), the same thing can be tested with a **different IRC client** ([Xchat](http://silverex.org/), [mIRC](http://mirc.com/)).

---

Also try connecting to a different port instead of the usual 6667. (`chat.freenode.net` allows **8001** among others.)

Comment: I am afraid it may be some sort of firewall issue.  Changing ports from 6667 to 7000 allows me to connect to chat.freenode.net.  But my other irc servers only serve off of 6667.  I tried adding rules to the firewall to clear port 6667 but it seems to have no effect.

Comment: Maybe use a SSL connection as a workaround? (Most networks have it on port 6697 or 9999.) Also, what firewall are you using?